# Install Jenkins using Helm in Kubernetes (kubeadm)

Tags: jenkins, proxy, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubeadm

First of all, I have Kubernetes cluster behind the proxy environment.

I have three servers, master, node1, and node2.

I installed Jenkins using below command.

Create jenkine-project namespace and then

`helm install --name jenkins -f jenkins-values.yaml stable/jenkins --namespace jenkins-project`

jenkins-values.yaml is

```
Master:
  Name: jenkins-master
  Image: "jenkins/jenkins"
  ImageTag: "lts"
  ImagePullPolicy: "Always"
# ImagePullSecret: jenkins
  Component: "jenkins-master"
  UseSecurity: true
  AdminUser: admin
  AdminPassword: 1qaz2wsx
  Cpu: "200m"
  Memory: "512Mi"
  # Environment variables that get added to the init container (useful for e.g. http_proxy)
  InitContainerEnv:
    - name: http_proxy
      value: "http://168.219.yyy.zzz:8080"
    - name: https_proxy
      value: "http://168.219.yyy.zzz:8080"
    - name: no_proxy
      value: "localhost,127.0.0.1,10.251.141.*,"
  ContainerEnv:
    - name: http_proxy
      value: "http://168.219.yyy.zzz:8080"
    - name: https_proxy
      value: "http://168.219.yyy.zzz:8080"
  JavaOpts: >-
    -Dhttp.proxyHost=168.219.yyy.zzz
    -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
    -Dhttps.proxyHost=168.219.yyy.zzz
    -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080
  # Set min/max heap here if needed with:
  # JavaOpts: "-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
  # JenkinsOpts: ""
  # JenkinsUriPrefix: "/jenkins"
  # Set RunAsUser to 1000 to let Jenkins run as non-root user 'jenkins' which exists in 'jenkins/jenkins' docker image.
  # When setting RunAsUser to a different value than 0 also set FsGroup to the same value:
  # RunAsUser: <defaults to 0>
  # FsGroup: <will be omitted in deployment if RunAsUser is 0>
  ServicePort: 8080
  # For minikube, set this to NodePort, elsewhere use LoadBalancer
  # Use ClusterIP if your setup includes ingress controller
  ServiceType: LoadBalancer
  # Master Service annotations
  ServiceAnnotations: {}
  #   service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: https
  # Used to create Ingress record (should used with ServiceType: ClusterIP)
  # HostName: jenkins.cluster.local
  # NodePort: <to set explicitly, choose port between 30000-32767
  ContainerPort: 8080
  # Enable Kubernetes Liveness and Readiness Probes
  HealthProbes: true
  HealthProbesTimeout: 60
  SlaveListenerPort: 50000
  # Kubernetes service type for the JNLP slave service
  # SETTING THIS TO "LoadBalancer" IS A HUGE SECURITY RISK: https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/issues/1341
  SlaveListenerServiceType: ClusterIP
  SlaveListenerServiceAnnotations: {}
  LoadBalancerSourceRanges:
  - 0.0.0.0/0
  # Optionally assign a known public LB IP
  # LoadBalancerIP: 1.2.3.4
  # Optionally configure a JMX port
  # requires additional JavaOpts, ie
  # JavaOpts: >
  #   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=4000
  #   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
  #   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
  # JMXPort: 4000
  # List of plugins to be install during Jenkins master start
  InstallPlugins:
    - kubernetes:1.4
    - workflow-aggregator:2.5
    - workflow-job:2.17
    - credentials-binding:1.16
    - p4:1.8.7
    - blueocean:1.4.2
  # Used to approve a list of groovy functions in pipelines used the script-security plugin. Can be viewed under /scriptApproval
  ScriptApproval:
    - "method groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic parseText java.lang.String"
    - "new groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic"
    - "staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods leftShift java.util.Map java.util.Map"
    - "staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods split java.lang.String"
  # List of groovy init scripts to be executed during Jenkins master start
  InitScripts:
  #  - |
  #    print 'adding global pipeline libraries, register properties, bootstrap jobs...'
  # Kubernetes secret that contains a 'credentials.xml' for Jenkins
  # CredentialsXmlSecret: jenkins-credentials
  # Kubernetes secret that contains files to be put in the Jenkins 'secrets' directory,
  # useful to manage encryption keys used for credentials.xml for instance (such as
  # master.key and hudson.util.Secret)
  # SecretsFilesSecret: jenkins-secrets
  # Jenkins XML job configs to provision
  # Jobs: |-
  #   test: |-
  #     <<xml here>>
  CustomConfigMap: false
  # Node labels and tolerations for pod assignment
  # ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector
  # ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#taints-and-tolerations-beta-feature
  NodeSelector: {}
  Tolerations: {}

  Ingress:
    Annotations:
#     kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    # kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"

    TLS:
    # - secretName: jenkins.cluster.local
    #   hosts:
    #     - jenkins.cluster.local

Agent:
  Enabled: true
  Image: jenkins/jnlp-slave
  ImageTag: 3.10-1
# ImagePullSecret: jenkins
  Component: "jenkins-slave"
  Privileged: false
  Cpu: "200m"
  Memory: "256Mi"
  # You may want to change this to true while testing a new image
  AlwaysPullImage: false
  # You can define the volumes that you want to mount for this container
  # Allowed types are: ConfigMap, EmptyDir, HostPath, Nfs, Pod, Secret
  # Configure the attributes as they appear in the corresponding Java class for that type
  # https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin/tree/master/src/main/java/org/csanchez/jenkins/plugins/kubernetes/volumes
  volumes:
   - type: HostPath
     secretName: /var/run/docker.sock
     mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
  NodeSelector: {}
  # Key Value selectors. Ex:
  # jenkins-agent: v1

Persistence:
  Enabled: true
  ## A manually managed Persistent Volume and Claim
  ## Requires Persistence.Enabled: true
  ## If defined, PVC must be created manually before volume will be bound
  # ExistingClaim: pvc-jenkins-master

  ## jenkins data Persistent Volume Storage Class
  ## If defined, storageClassName: <storageClass>
  ## If set to "-", storageClassName: "", which disables dynamic provisioning
  ## If undefined (the default) or set to null, no storageClassName spec is
  ##   set, choosing the default provisioner.  (gp2 on AWS, standard on
  ##   GKE, AWS & OpenStack)
  ##
  StorageClass: "jenkins-pv"

  Annotations: {}
  AccessMode: ReadWriteOnce
  Size: 20Gi
  volumes:
  #  - name: nothing
  #    emptyDir: {}
  mounts:
  #  - mountPath: /var/nothing
  #    name: nothing
  #    readOnly: true

NetworkPolicy:
  # Enable creation of NetworkPolicy resources.
  Enabled: false
  # For Kubernetes v1.4, v1.5 and v1.6, use 'extensions/v1beta1'
  # For Kubernetes v1.7, use 'networking.k8s.io/v1'
  ApiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1

## Install Default RBAC roles and bindings
rbac:
  install: true
  serviceAccountName: default
  # RBAC api version (currently either v1beta1 or v1alpha1)
  apiVersion: v1beta1
  # Cluster role reference
  roleRef: cluster-admin
```

And pod `jenkins-694674f4bd-zqfpq` is created.

I run `kubectl logs jenkins-694674f4bd-zqfpq -n jenkins-project` command
here is problem.

```
# kubectl logs jenkins-694674f4bd-zqfpq -n jenkins-project
Error from server: Get https://10.251.141.74:10250/containerLogs/jenkins-project/jenkins-694674f4bd-zqfpq/jenkins: read tcp 10.251.141.xxx:34630->168.219.yyy.zzz:8080: read: connection reset by peer
```

In this error message, 10.251.141.xxx is the master server's IP address and
168.219.yyy.zzz:8080 is proxy address.

And (I guess) because of this problem plugin will not be installed normally.

What is the problem and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood, you have a cluster behind a proxy, so it looks like that:

```
You | Proxy| All Kubernetes nodes and master
```

When you call `kubectl logs` command, `kubectl` is connecting to the API server and then the API server is [getting logs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#logging-at-the-node-level) of your pod from the node.

As I see from the output of the command, the API server is trying to connect to the node through the proxy server instead of direct connection, that's why I think you have a bit incorrect setup of proxy settings on your master.

Try to add all cluster internal IP ranges to exception using `no_proxy` on the master and on nodes, I think it should help.